# Webhooks not sending data to external application

Tags: node.js, post, webhooks, podio

Here is what I want to do:

- When an item is created within a certain app, a webhook sends the data contained within that item to an external application
- Same thing happens what an item is edited or deleted

Naturally, I'm using the native Podio webhooks. I made a hook for item.create, item.update, and item.delete. The external URLs are correct and clicking the "verify" button sends a successful call to the external app.

However, none of the actions actually work. I've created, changed, and deleted items - nothing. Only clicking the "verify" button causes any communication with the external app.

What are some common reasons why this might not be working?

Answer (score 2):

Have you activated that webhook? From Podio documentation https://developers.podio.com/examples/webhooks

> Before your webhooks becomes active the URL must be verified. Immediately after the webhooks is created a hook.verify notification is sent to the URL endpoint. The endpoint must then return the code to the validation operation. Events will only be sent to the endpoint after a completed verification.

Example with command line curl:
Please remember to inject correct `access_token`, `hook_id` and `verification_code`

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: OAuth2
>   [access_token]" -X POST -d "{'code': [verification_code]}"
>   https://api.podio.com/hook/[hook_id]/verify/validate

Comment: I'm looking at https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/validate-hook-verificated-215241, but this only gives examples in PHP and Ruby. Furthermore, these rely on libraries written for Podio and don't lend themselves to a generic solution. Can you please tell me the full URL of where the POST request should go and a full example of what the contents should look like?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I managed to **verify my Node.JS webhook endpoint** and make it **active** using `Express.JS`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app     = express();
const https = require('https');

app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', function(request, response){

  console.log( "POST", request.body);

  // VERIFICATION >>
  const postData = JSON.stringify({ code: request.body.code });
  const options = {
      hostname: 'api.podio.com',
      port: 443,
      path: '/hook/' + request.body.hook_id + '/verify/validate',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'accept': 'application/json'
      }
  };
  const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
          console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
          console.log('No more data in response.');
      });
  });
  req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
  });
  req.write(postData);
  req.end();
  // << VERIFICATION
  
  response.send(request.body);

});

app.listen(443);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. I've since lost access to the Podio project, but this looks like it should work.